# TYPO3 Backend - clicking on "Add media file" shows blank section

Tags: php, typo3, typo3-10.x

A client of mine has the error that **sometimes** When he tries to upload a Picture inside a text & media element via "Add media file" the fileadmin section is not loaded. I was not able to reproduce and my google search did not help me. I would like to give my client an explanation why this could happen. Does anyone have an idea? He uses PHP 7.4.3 and TYPO3 10.4.6, thats all information I got..

[image]

Comment: do you have any code?

Comment: Please provide more details about the environment where your client is running this. Maybe it is some error in Typo3 loading the fileadmin?

Comment: Also please explain the printscreen.

Comment: Actually this is laughable "Closed. This question needs details or clarity. It is not currently accepting answers." as in a case like this no details are available.

Answer (score 2):

The fault is most likely a network problem.
If something like this happens the browser-console can be opened to get a confirmation about the loading-problem of files and data.
"Debugging" network-errors is certainly not solving the resulting faults on client-side.
Verifying hardware and perhaps limited capacity on the client-side could bring up some options like increasing memory, repairing cable-connections, etc.. If on that side no faults can be found then the network itself might be unstable or overloaded.